# Centos htaccess not being read

Tags: .htaccess, lamp

I'm working on a new server and I installed via yum the "Web Server" group. Php and mysql work fine but I can't get .htaccess to work.

Heres my test .htaccess file:

```
WASD_TEST_CALL_ERROR
```

I put this as .htaccess in a test folder along with an index.html page. 
Instead of reporting an error it goes ahead and loads the index page without displaying any errors.

Thanks

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Make sure AccessFileName set to .htaccess

Search httpd.conf for AccessFileName directive. It defines name of the distributed configuration file:

```
grep -i AccessFileName httpd.conf
```

Make sure users are allowed to use .htaccess file

What you can put in these files is determined by the AllowOverride directive. This directive specifies, in categories, what directives will be honored if they are found in a .htaccess file. If this directive is set to None, then .htaccess files are completely ignored. In this case, the server will not even attempt to read .htaccess files in the filesystem.

```
grep -i AllowOverride httpd.conf
```

When this directive is set to All, then any directive which has the .htaccess Context is allowed in .htaccess files:
`AllowOverride All`

Save and close the file. Restart httpd:

```
service httpd restart
```

Comment: If you're getting `Failed to restart httpd.service: The name org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1 was not provided by any .service files` then you need to do `sudo httpd restart`

Answer (score 4):

On CentOS7, the following should help:

1. Under string *AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files* in `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`:replace AllowOverride None to `AllowOverride All`
2. In /etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/00-base.conf check **rewrite_module** must be:

   `LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so`
3. .htaccess file must be in **/var/www/html/**
4. Example content .htaccess:

   `AuthUserFile /var/www/.htpasswd
   AuthGroupFile /dev/null
   AuthName "Please Enter Password"
   AuthType Basic
   Require valid-user`
5. check and restart Apache:

   `httpd -t`

   `/bin/systemctl restart  httpd.service`

Answer (score 3):

Have you set AllowOverride in Apache config? If not, set AllowOverride from `none` to `all`.

Answer (score 1):

1. /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:replace AllowOverride None to AllowOverride All
2. httpd -M | grep rewrite_module should result

   [image]

> rewrite_module (shared)

Still not working even after making sure all above in place? Then make sure your .htaccess has below line at the top.

```
RewriteEngine On
```

Answer (score 0):

> Go to /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf and find below line. htaccess Context is allowed in .htaccess files: AllowOverride All

Save and close the file. Restart httpd:
[image]

Comment: When showing code, please embed actual code and not an image of the code.