# Removing a index.php from codeginiter url using htaccess not working on server

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

.htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

also change in config file:

```
$config['index_page'] = ' ';

$config['uri_protocol'] = "REQUEST_URI";
```

mod_rewrite is also enabled.
although this code doesn't work.

Comment: What apache server are you running wamp lamp etc

Comment: apache server running...and server is in CentOS.

Comment: i am working with cassandra database

Comment: in cent os you have make a small change in ur httpd.conf file and take restart. .Htaccess won't work untill you make that change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this

In 'config.php`

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
$config['index_page'] = ''
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

`.htaccess`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L] 
</IfModule>
```

and accessing URL should with `base_url()` function.

ex `<form action="<?php echo base_url()?>Controller_name/Method_name"`

> ***Note:*** To use `base_url()` you have to enable it on `autoload.php`
>
> ```
> $autoload['helper'] = array('url');
> ```

Comment: The requested URL  was not found on this server

Comment: did you place my `.htaccess` ??

Comment: my server is in CentOS. is there any problem with the server?

Comment: @RubbySmith [Read this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8551740/centos-htaccess-not-being-read)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the `REQUEST_URI` protocol when you are asking Apache to send the URI to the `QUERY_STRING`.

So either change your `.htaccess` or your config so they match. My recommendation is to change `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Comment: And what about using your previous `.htaccess` code and then changing the protocol from `REQUEST_URI` to `QUERY_STRING`?

Comment: Also, there's an unnecessary space in the `index_page` setting. Change `' '` to `''`.

Comment: i have tried all the option of protocol but it can't work... i can't understand what is the problem

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried giving `AUTO` instead of `REQUEST_URI`. Even i had a similar problem but got solved when i changed it to `AUTO` and small change in .htaccess in my case.

```
$config['index_page'] = '';

$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

.htaccess-

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|public|\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1
```

OR

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

If doesn't works for your case sorry.

[CodeIgniter htaccess and URL rewrite issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14783666/codeigniter-htaccess-and-url-rewrite-issues)

Comment: Note: Codeigniter 3 does not have AUTO.

Answer (score 0):

I have running CI 3 Application and working fine with this .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```